# How to compare two lists and decide one matches the other?

Tags: python

For example, I have one list as below:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have another list `lx` to compare with `l1` and need to decide whether `lx` matches `l1`. A successful match is defined as below:

> For each element `e` in `lx`, `e` must be in `l1` too; and for any two sequential elements `e1` and `e2`, if `e1` appears before `e2`, then `e1` must also appear before `e2` in `l1`.

Some examples are below and their match status with l1 is provided:

```
l2 = [2, 1]      # fails
l3 = [1, 2, 4]   # succeeds
l4 = [2, 3]      # succeeds
l5 = [2, 3, 1]   # fails
l6 = [1,2,3,4,5] # fails
```

UPDATE for more complicated cases:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [{2}, {1}]
l2 = [{2,1}, {1,3}]
```

l1 doesn't change, but in the other list, it's always a set of lists. For this example:

```
l2 = [{2,1}, {1,3}]
```

It can be expanded into:

```
l2 = [[2,1], [2,3], [1,1], [1,3]]
```

which means as long as one of the 4 lists in l2 matches l1, it is a successful match. Since [1,3] matches l1=[1,2,3,4], the whole l2 can match.

So one solution may be first flatten the l2 into the new l2, and then the all(e in i for e in b) can be used.

Comment: Are the values unique?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, would gladly upvote if you show your previous efforts, because the question itself is well organzied...

Comment: You have multiple gold badges and a 7-year-old account, so you should well understand by now that [some research is expected before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), if only so that you can narrow down the question you ask to the *actual question that you have*. What part of this task do you find difficult? What happened when you tried to write the code?

Comment: @mozway, not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an efficient solution. For each element in the second list, get the next element of the first one until you have a match. If you reach the end of the first list before you matched all, this is `False` else `True`

```
def check(a, b):
    i = iter(a)
    return all(e in i for e in b)
```

Or manual version:

```
def check(a, b):
    i = iter(a)
    for e in b:
        try: 
            while e != next(i):
                pass
        except StopIteration:
            return False
    return True
```

Test:

```
for l in [l2, l3, l4, l5, l6]:
    print(check(l1, l))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: Looks like a complicated version of the old `return all(e in i for e in b)` :-P

Comment: @Kelly haven't slept for a while, allow me to be less pythonic that usual ;)

Comment: @mozway, can you please add back the first version of this more efficient algorithm? My actual case is more complicated and this current short version is less helpful than the original long version. I didn't save the longer version when you first post it.

Comment: @marlon check the [old revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70458685/revisions) of the answer, changes are tracked ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how different is your actual use case?

Comment: Let me update the original question.

Comment: @mozway please see my UPDATES.

Comment: @marlon I saw, however this is now a different problem. Also, sets are unordered, so you can't reliably generate your list of lists from the list of sets.

Comment: @mozway The way they want to use them, that unsortedness doesn't matter.

Comment: @mozway, 'generate your list of lists from the list of sets' won't be an issue. For example [{1}, {2,3}] == [[1,2], [1,3]] == [[1,3], [1,2]]. Would this make it easier?

Comment: The "manual" version would btw only need a tiny change, and the short version could use something neat (could be *very* neat if the `set` class wasn't missing a method...).

Comment: @KellyBundy I can't figure out how to make a new 'b' for the outer loop without first expanding the list of sets into list of lists.

Comment: If you unchange this question (I think it was bad to change it in the first place) and post it as a proper new question, I could answer it there.

Comment: Yes. I will write  a new one.

Comment: @KellyBundy, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70465931/how-to-do-sub-sequence-match-for-a-simple-list-and-a-list-of-sets

Answer (score 3):

A simple (non optimal) solution is to rework l1 to keep only elements of the second list, and check equality:

```
def check(a, b):
    S = set(b)
    return b == [x for x in a if x in S]

check(l1, l3)
```

Test:

```
for l in [l2, l3, l4, l5, l6]:
    print(check(l1, l))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: @Kelly can you elaborate?

Comment: This appears indeed a simple method.

Comment: Yes right, trivial to fix ;)

Comment: Why does the fix make a change by taking set(b) out? @mozway

Comment: @marlon because it's converted only once, vs as many times as there are elements in b. Oversight from my side ;)

Comment: @marlon What result do you want when the lists are [1, 1] and [1]?

Comment: I guess `False`, @marlon better use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458685/16343464) it is more efficient.

Comment: Why should it be `False`? It fulfills the criteria.

Comment: @KellyBundy, [1,1], [1], a good match.

Comment: Depends which one is l1, for [1] this is False as you only have a single 1, the other way around is True

Comment: I meant them in order of how the question presented them, i.e., [1,1] is the list l1 and [1] is the another list.

Comment: [1,1] must be l1 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def is_subsequence(list1, list2):
    return set(list2) <= set(list1) and list2 == sorted(list2, key=list1.index)
```

Not the most optimal method, but it basically sorts the smaller list using the indices of the main list and checks if the elements are still in the same positions:

```
print(is_subsequence(l1, [2, 1]))           # False
print(is_subsequence(l1, [1, 2, 4]))        # True
print(is_subsequence(l1, [2, 3]))           # True
print(is_subsequence(l1, [2, 3, 1]))        # False
print(is_subsequence(l1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # False
```